# Kinda recursive word counting

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, words

Today is one of those days where all of my knowledge in programming seems to be failing horribly, and no amount of coffee administered via IV is helping the situation.

I am presented with a list of phrases, here is some as an example

```
"tax policies when emigrating from uk"
"shipping to scotland from california"
"immigrating to sweden"
"shipping good to australia"
"shipping good to new zealand"
"how to emigrate to california from the uk"
"shipping services from london to usa"
"cost of shipping from usa to uk"
```

Now I need to start doing word frequency analysis on this, thankfully in python this is pretty simple, I constructed the following function to take this list and give back a `Counter` of the most common words.

```
from collections import Counter

def count(phrases):
    counter = Counter()
    for phrase in phrases:
        for word in phrase.split(" "):
            counter[word] += 1
    return counter
```

This rocks, because now I can easily acquire the most common words from the phrase list as so `count(phrases).most_common(5)`

Now it becomes harder. Say I set an arbitrary depth, lets say 5. Given the most popular word in that list (that isn't a glue word e.g. from or to and) is shipping. I now need to take the word shipping and count again for all the phrases that contain shipping the terms, again mostly kind of simple.

```
def filter_for_word(word, phrases):
    return filter(lambda x: word in x, phrases)
count(filter_for_word("shipping", phrases))
```

This is where it starts to get hairy, I need to keep going down and down the results until I hit my depth. And then I need to be able to display this information along with the most common phrases together.

I started trying to do this with the following function but I simply cannot get my head around the next few steps to bind the content together and display it in a good structure and format.

```
def dive(depth, num, phrases):
    phrase_tree = {}
    for word, value in dict(count(phrases).most_common(num)).iteritems():
        phrase_tree[word] = [value, {}]

    current = phrase_tree
    while True:
        if depth == 0:
            return phrase_tree
        for word in current:
            current[word][1] = {key: [v, {}] for (key, v) in count(filter_for_word(word, phrases)).most_common(num)}

        # debug!!
        return current
```

If anyone could help me bring this all together I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count the most popular words `w1` in all phrases, then the most popular words `w2` in the phrases that have `w1`, then the most popular words `w3` in the phrases that have `w2` in...?

Comment: You can simplify your counting with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`: `def count(phrases): return Counter(chain.from_iterable((w for w in p.split(" ")) for p in phrases))`. You don't need to manually `+= 1`, that's what `Counter` is for!

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_for_words(words, phrases):
    for word in words:
        phrases = filter(lambda x: word in x, phrases)
    return phrases


def dive(depth, num, phrases, phrase_tree=None, f_words=None):
    if not phrase_tree:
        phrase_tree = {}
        for word, value in dict(count(phrases).most_common(num)).iteritems():
            phrase_tree[word] = [value, {}]

    if not f_words:
        f_words = []

    while True:
        if depth == 0:
            return phrase_tree

        for word in phrase_tree:
            words = f_words[:]
            words.append(word)
            child_tree = {key: [v, {}] for (key, v) in count(filter_for_words(words, phrases)).most_common(num)}
            phrase_tree[word][1] = child_tree
            dive(depth-1, num, phrases, child_tree, words)

        return phrase_tree
```

Not efficiency but it should work.

Comment: This is okay but I want to remove replication in lower levels. E.g. `b["to"][1]["to"][1]["to"][1]["to"][1]["to"][1]["to"]` shouldn't be valid

Comment: @JakobBowyer So I suggest you to use a better data structure (implement a node class). Only using list and dict will make your code ugly.